# Excel VBA ADODB SQL sum if data matches

Tags: sql, vba, excel, adodb

This is the query I am currently using to generate my SQL string, which is currently getting the correct information.

```vb
Dim colArray As Variant: colArray = Array(7,9,6,8,10,11,15,25)                               

szSQL = "SELECT 
          sWIR.[F" & Join(colArray, "], sWIR.[F") & "], sCodes.[F7]
          FROM [" & SourceWIR & "] sWIR INNER JOIN [" & SourceCODES & "] AS sCodes ON sWIR.[F5] = sCodes.[F6] 
          WHERE sWIR.[F1] =""" & Address & """ 
          ORDER BY sCodes.[F7], sWIR.[F7];"
```

What I need it to include is if the data in columns 7, 9, 6 are equal then sum column 10

Below is the full code, I am using for the ADODB Connection

```vb
Dim szConnect As String, szSQL As String
Dim SourceFileName As String: SourceFileName = Left(wb.Name, Len(wb.Name) - 5)
Dim SourceFile As String: SourceFile = wb.FullName
Dim rsCon As New ADODB.Connection
Dim rsData As New ADODB.Recordset
szConnect = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & "Data Source=" & SourceFile & ";" & "Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=No"";"
rsCon.Open szConnect

Dim LastRow As Long: LastRow = wb.WIR.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
Dim LastCol As Long: LastCol = wb.WIR.Cells(1, wb.WIR.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

Dim SourceWIR As String: SourceWIR = wb.WIR.Name & "$"
Dim SourceCODES As String: SourceCODES = wb.CODES.Name & "$"

Dim colArray As Variant: colArray = Array(7,9,6,8,10,11,15,25)

szSQL = "SELECT  sWIR.[F" & Join(colArray, "], sWIR.[F") & "], sCodes.[F7]FROM [" & SourceWIR & "] sWIR INNER JOIN [" & SourceCODES & "] AS sCodes ON sWIR.[F5] = sCodes.[F6] " & _
        "WHERE sWIR.[F1] =""" & Address & """ ORDER BY sCodes.[F7], sWIR.[F7];"

rsData.Open szSQL, rsCon, adOpenKeyset, adLockOptimistic

wb.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A25").CopyFromRecordset rsData
```

Below is an image of what the data looks like now, and how the data should look when matches are found.

[image]

With help from Parfait, who provided me with the correct string.

After spending hours googling and testing I was able to get the correct string to exclude zero values.

```vb
szSQL = SELECT 
             main.[wF7], main.[F9], main.[F6], Max(main.[F8]) As maxF8,
             Sum(main.[F10]) As sumF10, Max(main.[F11]) As maxF11, 
             Max(main.[F15]) As maxF15, Max(main.[F25]) As maxF25, 
             Max(main.[sF7]) As maxsF7 
         FROM (
             SELECT 
                 sWIR.[F7] As wF7, sWIR.[F9], sWIR.[F6], sWIR.[F8], sWIR.[F10],
                 sWIR.[F11], sWIR.[F15], sWIR.[F25], sCodes.[F7] As sF7 
             FROM 
                 [Works Instruction Record$] AS sWIR 
             INNER JOIN 
                 [Codes$] AS sCodes 
             ON 
                 sWIR.[F5] = sCodes.[F6] 
             WHERE 
                 sWIR.[F1] ="1 Foney Road") AS main 
         GROUP BY 
             main.[wF7], main.[F9], main.[F6] 
         HAVING 
             Sum(main.[F10]) = 0 
         ORDER BY 
             Max(main.[sF7]), main.[wF7];
```

I found that when using a group by, I needed to use a having clause with the same sum statement used within the select.

Comment: Can you better explain what the problem is?

Comment: This is easier achieved by removing the fourth column (the one with test123) from your query and modifying the query to become a group-by query.

Comment: @jkpieterse, unfortunately I need to keep the column that has the test123 as it has data that is needed. Can a group by still be used with this column? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned, consider an aggregate query grouped by first three columns, *F7*, *F9*, *F6*, summing *F10* and taking the max of all other non-grouped columns. Max/Min works on strings and numbers.

Notice your original query embedded as a derived table with aggregate on outside. Below is the SQL version to be incorporated into your VBA string. Do not use `Join()` due to `GROUP BY`:

```sql
SELECT main.[wF7], main.[F9], main.[F6], Max(main.[F8]) As maxF8, 
       Sum(main.[F10]) As sumF10, Max(main.[F11]) As maxF11, 
       Max(main.[F15]) As maxF15, Max(main.[F25]) As maxF25, Max(main.[sF7]) As maxsF7
FROM

  (SELECT sWIR.[F7] As wF7, sWIR.[F9], sWIR.[F6], sWIR.[F8], sWIR.[F10],
          sWIR.[F11], sWIR.[F15], sWIR.[F25], sCodes.[F7] As sF7
   FROM [" & SourceWIR & "] AS sWIR 
   INNER JOIN [" & SourceCODES & "] AS sCodes 
       ON sWIR.[F5] = sCodes.[F6]
   WHERE sWIR.[F1] ='" & Address & "') AS main

GROUP BY main.[wF7], main.[F9], main.[F6]
ORDER BY Max(main.[sF7]), main.[wF7]
```

Comment: thank you this work perfectly!! It would have taken me ages to get to this on my own. Is is possible to exclude rows where [F10] = 0. Thanks for the assistance.

Comment: I think i managed to follow along correctly and got it to work, i am still new to using SQL and especially aggregate queries, but i add 'WHERE NOT main.[F10] = 0' just before the group by, which seems to be working, is this is wrong please do let me know. Thank You

Comment: Nope, `WHERE` clause should go before `GROUP BY`. Glad to help! Happy coding!

Comment: Hello there, i know its been a couple of weeks, but i have been doing some further testing, and i am still getting zeros in F10, could i pick your brain again please. Thank You

Comment: Maybe *F10* is a string, try wraping 0 in quotes: `WHERE NOT main.[F10] = '0'`

Comment: Hi, thanks for getting back to me, it turns out I needed to use Having, after the group by.